# T has incompatible bounds - Java generics

Tags: java, generics, playing-cards

I'm trying to learn generics through making a generic `Card` and `Deck` class which looks like this;

**Card.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;

public class Card<S extends Comparable<S>, R extends Comparable<R>> implements Comparable<Card<S, R>> {
    private S suit;
    private R rank;

    public Card(S suit, R rank) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Card{" +
                "suit=" + suit +
                ", rank=" + rank +
                '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Card<S, R> o) {
        return rank.compareTo(o.rank);
    }
}
```

**Deck.java**

```
package com.tn.deck;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;


public final class Deck<T extends Card> {
    private List<T> deck;

    public <S extends Comparable<S>, R extends Comparable<R>> Deck(int numberOfDecks, S[] suits, R[] ranks) {
        this.deck = initializeDecks(numberOfDecks, suits, ranks);
        shuffle();
    }


    private <S extends Comparable<S>, R extends Comparable<R>> List<T> initializeDecks(S[] suits, R[] ranks) {
        return Arrays.stream(suits)
                .flatMap(suit -> Arrays.stream(ranks).map(rank -> new Card<>(suit, rank)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); // === It complains here. ===
    }

    private <S extends Comparable<S>, R extends Comparable<R>> List<T> initializeDecks(int numberOfDecks, S[] suits, R[] ranks) {
        return IntStream.range(0, numberOfDecks)
                .mapToObj(i -> initializeDecks(suits, ranks))
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()); 
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(deck);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Deck{" +
                "deck=" + deck +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The error I get is

```
Error:(57, 25) java: incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: T
    lower bounds: com.tn.deck.Card<S,R>
```

It's probably just me not understanding generics, but I would really appreciate someone explaining to me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: For what it's worth, neither of your classes should really be using generics.

Comment: @GriffeyDog This is mostly for learning purposes anyway.

Comment: Do you have more than one suit type and more than one rank type? What types have you written or plan to use that could substitute for `S` and `R` in a concrete `Card<S, R>` type? Generics​ are assertions about types, not instructions. Your type assertions allow `Card<SSLEngineResult.HandshakeStatus, MultipleGradientPaint.CycleMethod>` or  `Card<RetentionPolicy, PosixFilePermission>`. How would you handle those?

Comment: @LewBloch Excellent points. I have to re-think the whole structure.

Comment: As @GriffeyDog suggested​, these classes should not be generic, unless you have perhaps an interface like `public interface Rank extends Comparable<Rank>` that different enums or other classes implement. Then you might have `public enum StandardRank implements Rank` and `public class Card<R extends Rank, S extends Suit>`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're creating `Card`, but must return `List<T>`. And `T` may be any subtype of `Card`, not `Card` itself.

When you're working with a generic class and need to create a new instance of `T` (or whatever erased generic type), you should accept a factory which is able to do so. For example:

```
public <S extends Comparable<S>, R extends Comparable<R>> Deck(int numberOfDecks, S[] suits, R[] ranks, BiFunction<S, R, T> cardFactory) {
    this.deck = initializeDecks(numberOfDecks, suits, ranks, cardFactory);
    shuffle();
}


private <S extends Comparable<S>, R extends Comparable<R>> List<T> initializeDecks(S[] suits, R[] ranks, BiFunction<S, R, T> cardFactory) {
    return Arrays.stream(suits)
            .flatMap(suit -> Arrays.stream(ranks).map(rank -> cardFactory.apply(suit, rank)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private <S extends Comparable<S>, R extends Comparable<R>> List<T> initializeDecks(int numberOfDecks, S[] suits, R[] ranks, BiFunction<S, R, T> cardFactory) {
    return IntStream.range(0, numberOfDecks)
            .mapToObj(i -> initializeDecks(suits, ranks, cardFactory))
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Never used `BiFunctions` before. Will definitely give that a go.

Comment: @Nilzone-, `BiFunction` is just a single abstract method interface (SAM-interface) which declares a function that accepts two arguments and returns a value. See also: functional interfaces, `Function`, `Supplier`, `Consumer`.

Answer (score 1):

why this error occurs? the generic parameter `T extends Card` is all of the subclass of `Card` including itself is allowed here. when the generic parameter `T` is a subclass type of `Card`, then the error occurs where your code `initializeDecks` try to return a superclass instance without casting. let's see a simple concrete example:

```
class Superclass{}
class Subclass extends Superclass{}

Subclass sub= ...;
// you can assign subclass's instance to superclass since it is-a superclass
Superclass sup = sub;
// you can assign superclass's instance to subclass you need casting it down
Subclass sub2 = (Superclass) sup;
```

you can fix your code as below:

```
<S extends Comparable<S>, R extends Comparable<R>> 
        List<? super T> initializeDecks(...){ 
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the method that's getting the error, you are creating a bunch of `Card<S, R>` objects and then trying to put them into a `List`. In order for that to work, the `List` needs to be able to hold objects of that type.

A `List<T>` can hold an object if and only if the object's class is `T` or a subclass of `T`. So, for this line to work, `Card<S, R>` has to be a subclass of `T`. Now if you look at the constraints on `T`, what you specify is that `T` is a subclass of `Card`. This constraint does not guarantee the relationship that putting the cards in the list requires, so you get an error.